# How convert class 'proc_time' output into a dataframe?

Tags: r, csv

I'm learning R and I'm analyzing the execution time of variables, but I want to go from 1 up to n (approx of 500 or more values) and have a record of the execution times. My code is not giving an error. However, the output of the csv file is not in the format I want.

My code:

```
data = system.time(result <- lgamma(500))
result_set <- data.matrix(data)
write.csv(result_set, "C:\\Users\\test.csv")
```

**CSV Output format**

[image]

**Format I want**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose your data. The function t() will do the trick.

```
result_set <- t(data.matrix(data))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Nicolás!